# Getting memory leak error when I click on signout button

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, reactfire

When I press sign out button. It shows me this error

> index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
> in SignedInLinks (at SideBar.js:12)

I want to know why this statement is causing memory leak.
This code is inside Sidebar.js

```
const {currentUser} = useAuth(); 

const links = currentUser ? <SignedInLinks profile={currentUser.photoURL} /> : <SignedOutLinks />;
```

When i paste like this without conditional rendering , it works fine

```
<SignedInLinks />
 <SignedOutLinks />
```

Logout function inside `<SignedInLinks />` component

```
const logout = () => {
    try {
        setLoading(true)
        githubSignOut();
        history.push("/solutions");
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    setLoading(false)
}
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Code looks fine not sure what the issue is ,could you provide the entire fcomponent?

Comment: Are you updating currentUser inside any of those "links"?

Comment: I add a logout function in the above code please check the code. This logout logic runs when I click on the signout button. This code is inside the <SignedInLinks /> component. I just remove the async await from this function. Now, it's working fine, not showing memory leak error. How this happens after removing async-await from the logout function?